# difference between openerp module and openerp web module

Tags: openerp-7

I want to understand what is the difference between openerp module and openerp web module? or both are complementary?

Some documents talk of openerp server side and other talk of client side.

My objective is to create a new module in openerp, I follow many documents that explains how create a module but they are too basic. Now, I want to understand the link between the web module and the basic module?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on what you want you module to do. If you only want to change the javascript client side behaviour of OpenErp. Then you should be a web module.

If you want to access the ORM models and write python code that will execute on the server, then you create a openerp module.

I don't you can simply call all modules in OpenERP simply modules. They share simular structure, way to install. But as the client side in OpenERP is javascript, you write it in javascript, and why the call it web module.